# Entity framework code first access to CSSpace

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

is there any way how to actually get to the CSSpace in entity framework 6 code first?

I tried to convert `DbContext` to `ObjectContext` like this:

```
 public static ObjectContext ToObjectContext(this DbContext dbContext)
        {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
        }
```

but how can I get access to the CSSpace via the ObjectContext?

thanks for answers, any help would be appreciated, I tried a lot but it seems that nothing works :/

Comment: CSSpace maps entity model to storage model - and says how are things realised on database level (including table and column names and the relationships between them). And I need to gain access to highlighted collection on this image: http://postimg.org/image/9ctuclzbr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem and came across a few links online which I tweaked and build the extension methods below.  `TableMapping` and `ColumnMapping` are just simple classes I use to store the translation data, so you can just ignore those.

I adapted snippets of Måns Tånneryd code from his [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107206/improving-bulk-insert-performance-in-entity-framework) 
(half way down).

The biggest issue with CSSpace is that most of the information you need is not exposed. Thus the most useful part of this is the use of reflection to get array and property data.  Hopefully, this help.  feel free to ping me if you need any further explanation.

```
      public static IEnumerable<TableMapping> GetMappings(this DbContext context)
            {


  List<TableMapping> tableMappings = new List<TableMapping>();

            var storageMapping = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItem<GlobalItem>(((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSSpace);

            dynamic entitySetMaps = storageMapping.GetType().InvokeMember(
                "EntitySetMaps",
                BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance,
                null, storageMapping, null);

            foreach (var entitySetMap in entitySetMaps)
            {
                var typeMappings = GetArrayList("EntityTypeMappings", entitySetMap);
                dynamic typeMapping = typeMappings[0];
                dynamic types = GetArrayList("Types", typeMapping);

                var fragments = GetArrayList("MappingFragments", typeMapping);
                var fragment = fragments[0];

                var tableSet = GetProperty("TableSet", fragment);
                var tableName = GetProperty("Name", tableSet);

                TableMapping tm = new TableMapping
                {
                    Entity = context.FindContextTableName((string)types[0].Name),
                    Table = tableName
                };

                var properties = GetArrayList("AllProperties", fragment);

                List<ColumnMapping> columnMappings = new List<ColumnMapping>();
                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    var edmProperty = GetProperty("EdmProperty", property);
                    var columnProperty = GetProperty("ColumnProperty", property);

                    ColumnMapping cm = new ColumnMapping
                    {
                        Property = edmProperty.Name,
                        Column = columnProperty.Name
                    };
                    columnMappings.Add(cm);
                }

                tm.Columns = columnMappings.AsEnumerable();
                tableMappings.Add(tm);
            }

            return tableMappings.AsEnumerable();
        }

        private static ArrayList GetArrayList(string property, object instance)
        {
            var type = instance.GetType();
            var objects = (IEnumerable)type.InvokeMember(
                property,
                BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, instance, null);
            var list = new ArrayList();
            foreach (var o in objects)
            {
                list.Add(o);
            }
            return list;
        }

        private static dynamic GetProperty(string property, object instance)
        {
            var type = instance.GetType();
            return type.InvokeMember(property, BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, instance, null);
        }
```