# Move large amount of data from old database to new database using Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, large-data

I'm creating an application to move data from old to new database (different schema). I'm using `Visual Studio 2013`, `C#`, `Entity Framework 5`, `Microsoft SQL Server 2012`. This table, `Customer`, has more than **40 thousand records**.

```
private void TransferCustomer()
{
    int counter = 0;

    // Load all old customers
    var oldCustomers = _oldRockDale.customers;

    foreach (var oldCustomer in oldCustomers)
    {
        // Create new customer
        ...

        // Modify something
        ...

        // Add to collection
        <New_database_entity>.Customers.Add(newCustomer);

        // Insert to database for each 1000 records
        counter++;
        if (counter % 1000 == 0)
        {
            <New_database_entity>.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    // Insert the rest to database
    <New_database_entity>.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here is my problem: **this function runs slower and slower. For the first 1000 records, it's just about 20 - 30 seconds. But it becomes much slower as it goes. Then, it takes more than 1 minutes to reach 2000.**

My questions are:

- Why does it run slower and slower?
- Is there any better way to transfer a large amount of data like this?

One more information: as I observe in `Output` window:

- Only 1 line saying that **thread exited with code 0**.
- After that, there are many lines saying **thread exited with code
  259**.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It gets slower and slower because of change tracking.

Comment: I'll try disabling it and wait the result. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: Change tracking is mostly useful. You might prefer to create more db contexts instead (one per 1,000 entities).

Comment: Fortythousand rows is nowhere near "large" in my eyes... BTW: You can move and convert data easily with the SQL Server Management Studio (if your DBMS is SQL Server, which you didn't tell us yet).

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQL Server. I use C# application because I'm not good at SQL and some data need modification. And I have the same thought with you, 40k rows is not large. But why does my application run slower and slower?

Comment: @ta.speot.is: you mean doing it parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is linked to the growth of the DbContext.

You can take advantage of the following posts:

- [Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework)
- [Improving bulk insert performance in Entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107206/improving-bulk-insert-performance-in-entity-framework)

Basically you have to insert by parts of 100 rows for example, and reset (as set again, that is: `_context = new SomeContext();`) the context between each insert.