# EF Insert entity with large number of new child entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've seen a number of "Bulk Insert in EF" questions however all of these deal with a usecase where a user is trying to insert a large array of items.

I've a situation where I have a new Parent entity with ~1500 new related entities attached to it. Both the parent and the child entities are mapped to their own tables in EF.

At the moment I'm using something like:

```
//p is already created and contains all the new child items    
public void SaveBigThing(Parent p){
  if(p.Id == 0){
    // we've got a new object to add
    db.BigObjects.Add(p);
  }
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Entity Framework at the moment creates an individual insert statement for each and every child item. Which takes 50 seconds or so. I want to be able to use `db.ChildEntity.AddRange(items)` But I'm unsure if there's a better way than to use 2 separate operations. First create the parent to get it's Id then a `AddRange` for all the child items?

Answer (score 0):

> IMHO You dont need to add parent first in-order to insert child items. You could do that in one shot.

You could try this in EF 5 `AddRange` is only available in `EF 6` or higher.

**This will not insert the item in bulk it will generate the query and insert at one shot**

[Ef bulk insertion reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6108279/1876572)

[Another reference](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Dec/22/Entity-Framework-and-slow-bulk-INSERTs)

```
public bool InsertParent(Parent parentObject)
{   
    //Assuming this is the parent table
    db.BigObjects.Add(parentObject);
    InsertChilds(parentObject); //Insert childs
    db.SaveChanges();
}

public bool InsertChilds(Parent parentObject)
{
    // This will save more time . 
    DataContext).Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    foreach(var child in parentObject.Childs)
    {
        //This will set the child parent relation
        child.Parent = childParent;
        db.ChildEntity.Add(child);
    }
    DataContext).Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;

}
```

Comment: I'm using ef6. There also doesn't appear to be a .Insert method on a DbSet. I don't think this would bulk insert the child items anyway.

Comment: Sorry it was `Add()` i misplaced with `insert()` as i was using `UnitOfWork`

Comment: My issue is that SQL server is having to complete thousands of separate SQL inserts to add all the child items. I believe using the process you've described it will still do the same.

Comment: Yes i too believe the process is same, but in my experience i had inserted to 17K items within less than 2 mints time . There has more than 4 `tables` if you need more performance use `StoredProcedure`