# Entity Framework bulk insert with transaction management - Performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I followed the answer in the following link for improving the performance of entity framework for bulk inserts and updates.

[Improving bulk insert performance in Entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107206/improving-bulk-insert-performance-in-entity-framework)

1. Made save changes in batch of 1000
2. regeneration of the `DbContext` object after every save changes

I got the performance boost as expected.

But I have a requirement of rolling back the transaction while exception condition while performing bulk insert.

This becomes issue when we re initialize the `DbContext` object.

Is there any other way to use the transaction and rollback with the same setup under the exception condition?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

### Transaction

If you want to rollback changes, you will need to use a transaction.

You can share the same connection within all context you generate.

Here is a small example:

```
try
{
    var connection = new SqlConnection("[ConnectionString]");
    var trans = connection.BeginTransaction();

    while (condition)
    {
        using (TestContext context = new TestContext(connection))
        {
             // ...code..
        }
    }

    trans.Commit();
}
catch
{
    // ...code..
}

public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext(SqlConnection connection) : base(connection, false)
    {

    }

    // ...code...
}
```

### Bulk Insert

You are not performing a `BulkInsert`. You are currently fixing a performance issue with the `DetectChanges` methods that's called every time you use the `Add` method.

See: http://entityframework.net/improve-ef-add-performance

If you have 50,000 entities to insert, you are still performing 50,000 database round-trip which is **INSANELY** slow.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

This library is a paid library but let you to really perform BulkInsert.

Only a few database round-trip will be required

Example

```
// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(bulk => bulk.BatchSize = 100);

// Perform Bulk Operations
context.BulkDelete(customers);
context.BulkInsert(customers);
context.BulkUpdate(customers);

// Customize Bulk Operations
context.BulkInsert(customers, options => {
   options => options.IncludeGraph = true;
});
context.BulkMerge(customers, options => {
   options.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = 
        customer => customer.Code;
});
```

**EDIT:** Answer Comment

> the proposed library indeed looks great. But can you please elaborate regarding the transaction management with bulk operations?

Sure,

Documentation: http://entityframework-extensions.net/transaction

### BulkSaveChanges

As SaveChanges, BulkSaveChanges already save all entities within an internal transaction. So by default, there is nothing to do.

However, if you start a transaction within Entity Framework, BulkSaveChanges will honor it and will use this transaction instead of creating an internal transaction.

```
var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction();
try
{
    context.BulkSaveChanges();
    transaction.Commit();
}
catch
{
    transaction.Rollback();
}
```

### Bulk Operations

Bulk Operations such as BulkInsert, BulkUpdate, BulkDelete doesn’t use a transaction by default. This is your responsibility to handle it.

If you start a transaction within Entity Framework, Bulk Operations will honor it.

```
var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction();
try
{
    context.BulkInsert(list1);
    context.BulkInsert(list2);
    transaction.Commit();
}
catch
{
    transaction.Rollback();
}
```

Comment: the proposed library indeed looks great. But can you please elaborate regarding the transaction management with bulk operations?