# Deadlock when inserting new records to a specific table

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a background task (started by `IHostedService`) that runs every 7 days, this task copies data into the same table only changing the PKs to generate dummy data (it's used for demos).

The issue is when it tries to save the new data for the second table (approx 2k new records) Entity Framework never completes the `SaveChangesAsync` this process is blocked and it starts consuming the whole RAM available.

**Note**: The first table sometimes copies more than 20k new records.

This is my current code, I'm using Entity Framework Core 5.0.4 with .NET Core 3.1:

```cs
using (var context = _context.CreateNewInstance())
{
    var existingStudents = context.Students.Where(s => s.UniversityId == _destUniversity.Id);
    var sourceStudents = context.Students.Where(s => s.UniversityId == _sourceUniversity.Id)
                                         .Select(s => new Student()
                                         {
                                             //...properties
                                         });

    var newStudents = sourceStudents.Where(s => !existingStudents.Any(es => es.DiffKey == s.DiffKey)).ToArray();

    if (newStudents.Length == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    await context.Students.AddRangeAsync(newStudents);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync(_cancellationToken.Token);
}
```

I've tried all this:

1. [Disabling "Auto Detect Changes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107206/improving-bulk-insert-performance-in-entity-framework)
2. [Batch insert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5942176/2044647): this only works with the first batch.
3. [Use `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable`](https://www.sqlshack.com/reducing-sql-server-async_network_io-wait-type/)
4. A single context for all tables in the task
5. New context instance for each table
6. Compared the configuration of the databases/tables and replicated it on local

I have 2 servers (1 local, 1 remote) with 3 databases (1 local, 2 remote), the code works on two of the three databases (1 local and 1 remote).

I used this code to get the `spid` of the task on SQL:

```cs
int psid;

using (var command = contextTmp.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "select @@spid as id";
    contextTmp.Database.OpenConnection();

    using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        result.Read();
        psid = result.GetInt16("id");
    }

    contextTmp.Database.CloseConnection();
}
```

With the `spid` from the previous code I've monitored the requests on the [SQL Server](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/) side to check its status:

```sql
select session_id, 
    status, 
    command,
    blocking_session_id,
    wait_type, 
    wait_time,
    last_wait_type,
    wait_resource
from sys.dm_exec_requests 
where session_id = @id
```

Result:

| session_id | status | command | blocking_session_id | wait_type | wait_time | last_wait_type | wait_resource |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 84 | suspended | SELECT | 0 | ASYNC_NETWORK_IO | 35 | ASYNC_NETWORK_IO |  |

I've read blogs about this issue but I don't get it yet, I think I missing something. I ran out of ideas.

Other sources:

- [DBA stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107669/why-do-async-network-io-wait-types-occur)
- [Understanding how SQL Server executes a query](http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/)
- [SQL Server ASYNC Network IO Wait Type](https://logicalread.com/sql-server-async-network-io-wait-tl01)
- [Database Connection Hazards with Entity Framework](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/07/database-connection-hazards-with-entity-framework/)

UPDATE(1):

Before we've updated from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1 all functions worked well. We started to see strange behaviors after the upgrade.

Any suggestions?

Comment: FYI - thats not a deadlock. That straight blocking. A deadlock will be resolved very quickly with one process being rolled back.

Comment: good point, thank you. so, what is it?

Comment: As I said that is straight blocking.

Comment: oh ok, that's new for me, let me read something about it

Comment: I think the key is in the batch works, the first time. Likely a single stored command will be executed at any attempt? 

Likely the method isn't properly "closing" after execution, and the issue is that entityframework still thinks the table is being worked on, thus blocking another async process from making changes. 

Try to do the store without async, and see if that doesn't solve your problem, then you know for sure, if it is or not.

Comment: I've tried with sync methods, the same issue :(

Comment: What is it being blocked by (although ASYNC_NETWORK_IO usually indicates a lot of data being downloaded over a slow connection)? Are you running that code in a loop or is there another query that also runs?

Comment: I'm running this code from `DoWork` of `Threading.Timer` which is created by `IHostedService`. On my side, I only run this code once per week, one instance at a time, but there may be other applications trying to read/write into this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework is not good at inserting things in bulk. If an entity has an auto-generated primary key, then after each insert, EF will query the database to get the id of the entry. That means that for each of your 20K records, you have to wait for the round-trip time of the database. That's why everything appears to stop working when you call `SaveChanges()` - it's still running, but it will take a long time. There are a few ways to solve this:

- Change the id to be client generated
- Use an extension library like EntityFrameworkPlus to perform a bulk insert
- Use SqlBulkCopy instead of Entity Framework
- Use a stored procedure

Comment: I've changed the order of the tables, now the second table is the first, this with the purpose of avoiding the insertion of 20k records, but the problem still there

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. Are you still adding `newStudents` to the `Students` table? If so, how many records are you trying to add? That is the core problem in your original question, so if that has changed, you need to update the question with more details

Comment: oh sorry, let me explain, I'm inserting data for many tables, Students was the second one, the first table sometimes inserts more than 20k but not always (with this I don't have issues), so I've changed the order of the tables, now I add `newStudents` to `Students` before try to insert anything else to some other table.

Comment: CDC is part of the problem, if I disable it, everything works correctly, but it's required, so I changed the Id (and others properties) to be generated on the client-side and that solved the issue for now. Thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your query do not need transferring data to the client just INSERT FROM.
I propose to use third party extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (disclaimer, I'm one of the creators)

Then your query will be executed on the server side almost immediately:

```cs
using (var context = _context.CreateNewInstance())
{
    var existingStudents = context.Students.Where(s => s.UniversityId == _destUniversity.Id);
    var sourceStudents = context.Students.Where(s => s.UniversityId == _sourceUniversity.Id)
                                         .Select(s => new Student()
                                         {
                                             //...properties
                                         });

    var newStudents = sourceStudents.Where(s => !existingStudents.Any(es => es.DiffKey == s.DiffKey));

    await newStudents.InsertAsync(context.Students.ToLinqToDBTable(), x => x, _cancellationToken.Token);
}
```

Comment: Note that it will work only if you do not use in `sourceStudents` projection non-translatable to the SQL functions.